# trying to convert r code to function in python

Tags: r, python-3.x

I need to convert the code from R to python. I was trying with rpy2 but its not working with me.

R Code:

#Written function in R

```
con_filter <- function(dim,pred_date)
    {

 #Filtering the data for missing metric values and pred date

 con <- as.data.frame(subset(Ntpc,(Ntpc$dimension_key_group==dim & 
                                          Ntpc$pred_values != "NA" & 
                                         Ntpc$NN_1D != "NA" &
                                       Ntpc$prediction_date== pred_date)))
  #Finding Error Diff
  con$error_pred <- (con$metric_value - con$pred_values)
  con$error_NN <- (con$metric_value - con$NN_1D)

 #Calculating MAPE for indivigual records 
 con$mape_pred <- abs((con$error_pred)/con$metric_value)*100
con$mape_NN <- abs((con$error_NN)/con$metric_value)*100
}
```

Below is the python code:

```
#Trying to write function in python
def con_filter(dim,pred_date):
    con = [Ntpc[(Ntpc["dimension_key_group"] == 'dim') &
                                       (Ntpc["pred_values"] != ' ') & 
                                       (Ntpc["NN_1D"] != ' ') &
                                       (Ntpc["prediction_date"] == 'pred_date')]]                               
    con.error_pred = (con.metric_value - con.pred_values)
    con.error_NN = (con.metric_value - con.NN_1D)
    con.mape_pred = abs((con.error_pred)/con.metric_value)*100

    con.mape_NN = abs((con.error_NN)/con.metric_value)*100
    summ_month = pd.DataFrame()
    sum_month = con.groupby('data_date').agg({'mape_pred' : ['mean'], 'mape_NN' : ['mean']}).reset_index()
    return summ_month
```

Getting some error as follows:

> ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 9: given 1

Can anyone help me in this so that it would be great

Comment: Try running each statement on its own and examine the output. Is it what you would expect? Also, you seem to be calling `dim` as a string not as a variable. Is this OK?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad

Comment: Yes. I am using dim as string to pass values in the function.